# QGIS Hidden attributes not hidden in Relations

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, relation

I have a PostGIS view, which a referencing layer for another layer for `many to one relation` in QGIS. I have hidden the following fields `id, table_name, oid` of the postgis view so that the user would not see those fields in the attribute table. It does work in `form view`. The fields are hidden as in the image.

[image]

But they are visible in the attribute view. I tried `Hide Column` option in the attribute table but it did not work. Is there any way I can hide them both in form view and attribute view?

[image]